# Close each trade after a period of time

Tags: pine-script

I'm creating a Tradingview strategie with a specific entry signal. Each trade (pyramiding enabled) should be closed after 180 bars. Is there any possibility to enumerate open trades to get the open time or add a when condition to the strategie.exit if the specific position was opened n bars ago?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

if strategy.position_size != 0
    if bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1) >= 180-1
        strategy.close_all()
```

Comment: That is how I've implemented it already. Unfortunately it's not working with paramyding. It's closing all trades if the last trade is 180 bars ago.

Comment: Full source code or minimal example showing the problem can help.